# Apply heading for ToC and ToF

Tags: c#, ms-word

I use `Interop.Word` to create table of figures and table of content programmatically to a Word document.

```
//Range where ToF will be located  
Range rangeForTOCTOF = wordDoc.Range(0, 0);    

//Create ToF  
TableOfFigures tof = wordDoc.TablesOfFigures.Add(rangeForTOCTOF, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);  

wordDoc.TablesOfFigures[1].TabLeader = WdTabLeader.wdTabLeaderDots;
wordDoc.TablesOfFigures.Format = WdTofFormat.wdTOFFormal;
tof.Update();
```

How can I set a title above the ToF like "Table of Figures"?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line:

```
rangeForTOCTOF.InsertBefore("Table of Figures\n");
```

or:

```
rangeForTOCTOF.InsertAfter("Table of Figures\n");
```

Comment: if I place that code before the TOF creation the TOF replaces the "Table of Figures\n", if I move it after, the text replaces the TOF!  `rangeForTOCTOF.Text="Table of Figures\n";
        TableOfFigures tof = wordDoc.TablesOfFigures.Add(rangeForTOCTOF, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);`

Comment: What VSTO and Word version are you working on? and what .NET framework?

Comment: SharpDevelop is the work space, Word 10 with interop.Word Ver12. I use .Net 4